# BFS (Breadth First Search) - Not calculating the shortest Path in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I have a problem in calculating the shortest path through BFS algorithm in Java.

When I tried to define a path from Node 0 to Node 7 , I got this result. `(0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5)`

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my Node Class

```
public class Node {
  private final int value;
  private final Set<Node> siblingNodes;

  public Node(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    siblingNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
  }

  public Set<Node> getSiblingNodes() {
    return siblingNodes;
  }

  public boolean equals(Node compareTo) {
    return (compareTo.getValue() == value);
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void addSiblingNode(Node node) {
    siblingNodes.add(node); 
  }
}
```

Here is the code snippets shown below.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     *
     *        1             -> 5
     * 0 ->           -> 4
     *        2 -> 3        -> 6    -> 7
     *
     */
        Node node0 = new Node(0);

        Node node1 = new Node(1);
        Node node2 = new Node(2);
        node0.addSiblingNode(node1);
        node0.addSiblingNode(node2);    

        Node node3 = new Node(3);
        node2.addSiblingNode(node3);

        Node node4 = new Node(4);
        node3.addSiblingNode(node4);

        Node node5 = new Node(5);
        Node node6 = new Node(6);
        node4.addSiblingNode(node5);
        node4.addSiblingNode(node6);
        
        Node node7 = new Node(7);
        node6.addSiblingNode(node7);

        List<Node> shortestPath = getDirections(node0, node7);
        for(Node node : shortestPath) {
          System.out.println(node.getValue());
        }
      }

      public static List<Node> getDirections(Node sourceNode, Node destinationNode) {
        // Initialization.
        Map<Node, Node> nextNodeMap = new HashMap<Node, Node>();
        Node currentNode = sourceNode;
        Node previousNode = sourceNode;

        // Queue
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        queue.add(currentNode);

        /*
         * The set of visited nodes doesn't have to be a Map, and, since order
         * is not important, an ordered collection is not needed. HashSet is 
         * fast for add and lookup, if configured properly.
         */
        Set<Node> visitedNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
        visitedNodes.add(currentNode);

        //Search.
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
          currentNode = queue.remove();
          if (currentNode.equals(destinationNode)) {
            // Handle case where the node leading to the destinatino node
            // itself pointed to multiple nodes. In this case,
            // nextNodeMap is incorrect and we need to rely on the previously
            // seen node.
            // Also need to check for edge-case of start node == end node.
            if (!previousNode.equals(currentNode)) {
              nextNodeMap.put(previousNode, currentNode);
            }
            break;
          } else {
            for (Node nextNode : currentNode.getSiblingNodes()) {
              if (!visitedNodes.contains(nextNode)) {
                queue.add(nextNode);
                visitedNodes.add(nextNode);

                // Look up of next node instead of previous.
                nextNodeMap.put(currentNode, nextNode);
                previousNode = currentNode;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        // If all nodes are explored and the destination node hasn't been found.
        if (!currentNode.equals(destinationNode)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No feasible path.");
        }

        // Reconstruct path. No need to reverse.
        List<Node> directions = new LinkedList<Node>();
        for (Node node = sourceNode; node != null; node = nextNodeMap.get(node)) {
            directions.add(node);
        }

        return directions;
      }
    }
```

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I just shared it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use a `Map` to construct the path between nodes. But the probless is that you're overriding Values since there couldn't more than one entry with same Key (`4 -> 6` has been overridden with `4 -> 5`, and you received an incorrect result).

To solve this issue we can reverse the Map, i.e. the *Keys* would represent sibling-nodes (*keys are unique*), and *Values* - parent-nodes (values can be duplicated). And when the `destination` node was found (or all nodes has been visited) the path would be constructed in restored in reversed order, i.e. from `destination` to `source` (we would need to reverse the list).

Also **note** that a `HashSet` of visited nodes is redundant since this information is already reflected in the Map.

That how BFS implementation might look like:

```
public static List<Node> getDirections(Node source, Node destination) {
    Map<Node, Node> paths = new HashMap<>(); // Map of paths also allows to track the visited nodes
    Queue<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();  // is more performant than LinkedList
    queue.add(source);
    paths.put(source, null); // the starting point of the path
    
    boolean isFound = false;
    
    while (!isFound && !queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = queue.remove();
        
        for (Node sibling : current.getSiblingNodes()) {
            if (paths.containsKey(sibling)) continue;
            // update the Map of paths
            paths.put(sibling, current);
            // the target node was found
            if (sibling.equals(destination)) {
                isFound = true; // we need to terminate the search, no need to explore all nodes if the path is found
                break;
            }
            queue.add(sibling); // adding the sibling to the queue
        }
    }
    return getPath(source, destination, paths);
}
```

Helper method for generating the path:

```
public static List<Node> getPath(Node start, Node end, Map<Node, Node> paths) {
    List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
    Node current = end;
    path.add(current);
    while (current != start && current != null) { // if there's no path from start to end current eventually will become null
        path.add(paths.get(current));
        current = paths.get(current);
    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return current != null ? path : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

***Note** `equals()` implementation in the `Node` class actually doesn't override `java.lang.Object.equals()` because the signature doesn't match. Also, implementation of `hashCode()` is missing, which goes against the contract of the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). Therefore, in hash-based collections, default implementations for both `equals` and `hashCode` would be used. It didn't cause troubles in the original code, only because OP was using literally the same objects.*

Here's an example of correct implementation:

```
public class Node {
    private final int value;
    private final Set<Node> siblingNodes = new HashSet<>();
    
    // constructor, getters, addSiblingNode(), etc.
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Node other && value == other.value;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // sample data from the question
    
    List<Node> shortestPath = getDirections(node0, node7);
    
    String path = shortestPath.stream()
        .map(Node::getValue)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" -> "));

    System.out.println(path);
}
```

*Output:*

```
0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDirections()` implementation seems correct. But there is a problem with the `Node` class. You should add the following two methods to `Node`.
These are needed to store `Node` objects in a `Map` or `Set`.

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Node n
            && n.value == value;
    }
```

output:

```
0
2
3
4
6
7
```